# Mapping Enum to Type

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I'm trying to use [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) on an enum:

```
export enum CurrencyType {
  USD = "USD",
  AUD = "AUD",
  GBP = "GBP",
  CAD = "CAD"
}
```

to achieve this type:

```
type Rates = {
  AUD: number;
  CAD: number;
  GBP: number;
  USD: number;
}
```

I thought I could do something like this:

```
type Rates = {
  [P in keyof CurrencyType]: number;
};
```

but that results in this instead:

```
type Rates = {
    toString: number;
    charAt: number;
    charCodeAt: number;
    concat: number;
    indexOf: number;
    lastIndexOf: number;
    localeCompare: number;
    match: number;
    replace: number;
    //...
}
```

I tried using `union literals` instead of `enum`,

```
export type CurrencyType = "USD" | "AUD" | "GBP" | "CAD";`
```

but it gives the same result.

The only thing I can get to work, is by doing this:

```
type Rates = {
  [P in typeof CurrencyType.AUD | CurrencyType.USD | CurrencyType.GBP | CurrencyType.CAD]: number;
};
```

but obviously that defeats the whole purpose!

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

wow it was right in front of me.  As always, I was over complicating it and not reading the documentation thoroughly.

```
type Rate = {
  [P in CurrencyType]: number;
};
```

I'll leave this up in case it helps someone else

Comment: Thank you for leaving it up and helping a stranger :-)