# Custom Key / Value type from enum and interface

Tags: typescript

I am looking for a custom type that would allow me to create an object with keys from a enum and that all match the value from a specific interface. Is there an easy way to create the `Custom` type below?

```
enum MyKeys {
  ALPHA = 'ALPHA',
  BETA = 'BETA',
  GAMMA = 'GAMMA',
}

interface MyValues {
  in: any[];
  out: any[];
}

type Example = Custom<MyKeys, MyValues>
```

Should be valid against:

```
{
  [MyKeys.ALPHA]: {
    in: []
    out: []
  },
  [MyKeys.BETA]: {
    in: []
    out: []
  },
  [MyKeys.GAMMA]: {
    in: []
    out: []
  }
}
```

Comment: `Record<MyKeys, MyValues>` ?

Comment: @jcalz that's it, if you answer I will approve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mapping Enum to Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48914818/mapping-enum-to-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just looking for the `Record<K, V>` type from [the standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.2.2/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1439-L1444).  It's a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) where the value types don't depend on the keys.  The ability to use string-based enums as key types in TypeScript was [added](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18029) in TypeScript 2.6.

Let's see it in action:

```
type Example = Record<MyKeys, MyValues>
const ex: Example = {
  [MyKeys.ALPHA]: {
    in: [],
    out: []
  },
  [MyKeys.BETA]: {
    in: [],
    out: []
  },
  [MyKeys.GAMMA]: {
    in: [],
    out: []
  }
}; // works
```

Looks good.  Hope that helps; good luck.