# Map enum values to individual types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, enums

I have a piece of TypeScript code like this:

```
enum EventType {
  EVENT_A = 'eventA',
  EVENT_B = 'eventB',
  ... // more event types
}

interface Event {
  type: EventType;
}

interface EventA extends Event {
  type: EventType.EVENT_A;
  data: PayloadForEventA;
}

interface EventB extends Event {
  type: EventType.EVENT_B;
  data: PayloadForEventB;
  id: number;
}

... // More Event interfaces
```

Is it possible to somehow map the values of `EventType` to corresponding interfaces? If it could not be done automatically, is it possible to specify the types mapped by the enum values manually?

I do know that it is possible to map values to types as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48914818/mapping-enum-to-type). And using the method shown below, it could create the lookup table I needed:

```
type EventTypeLut = {
  'eventA': EventA,
  'eventB': EventB,
  // ...
};
```

But this method hardcodes the value of enum into the LUT. The enum value might change in the future (which I don't have much control) and hardcoding the enum value makes it harder to maintain.

When I try to use `EventType.EVENT_A` as key name, TypeScript complains with "property or signature expected". Using template string seems also no avail. (It seems that the key name cannot be computed, even if it's a constant expression like `1+2`.)

The reason I am trying to do this is I would like to create a typed `EventEmitter` with the enum value of `EventType` as name and respective typed object for callback function.
If there is a better way to achieve this, please also give a hint. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object literals (and thus interfaces and object types) can have computed keys. For example:

```js
const obj = {
  [2 + 2]: 'four'
};
obj[2 + 2] === 'four'; // true
obj[1 + 3] === 'four'; // true
obj[4]     === 'four'; // true
obj['4']   === 'four'; // true
```

Computed keys are expressions wrapped in brackets that can be used as keys of an object literal, interface, or object type.  Try using computed keys for your `EventTypeLut` object type:

```
type EventTypeLut = {
  [EventType.EVENT_A]: EventA,
  [EventType.EVENT_B]: EventB,
  // ...
};
```

Comment: Is there a way of "typing the type", or making sure that all of the `EventType` keys are included in `EventTypeLut`?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @chharvey 's answer, you could also ensure all of the `EventType` keys are included in the `EventTypeLut` by doing something like:

```
type EventTypeLut = {
  [T in EventType]: {
    [EventType.EVENT_A]: EventA,
    [EventType.EVENT_B]: EventB,
  }[T]
};
```

The `[T in Event]` will cause TypeScript to complain if not all of the enum members are provided.

Comment: I asked a follow-up question about how to enforce that the values corresponding to the enum keys match a certain other type, maybe you know the answer and/or this link will be helpful for other people who found this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74021822/5602521